# How do you split string and show length?

Tags: c#, .net

I wonder how do i split a string from a Text Box and show length of the string. 
My current code doesn't work - i wonder what is wrong, because ide doesn't show me any errors, but i cant really put my mind to it.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp4
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string hello =  stringTextBox.Text;
            string[] final = hello.Split(' ');

            int showNumber = final.Length;

            Console.WriteLine("the length of " + hello + " is " + showNumber);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of concatenating strings, use formatting like `string.Format("Length of {0} is {1}", hello, hello.Length);` or `$"Length of {hello} is {hello.Length}"`

Comment: Also take a look at [`Length`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.length(v=vs.110).aspx) property and [`Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) method with different overloads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Split()` is used to split string on substrings using some separator and it returns substrings as array of strings.

In you code:

```
string[] final = hello.Split(' '); // split by space(`" "`)

int showNumber = final.Length;
```

`showNumber` will contain number of substrings splitted by using `Split()` method (length of resulted array).

If you want to get length of string just use `Length` property:

```
Console.WriteLine("the length of " + hello + " is " + hello.Length);
```

**EDIT (After your comment):**

To get number of words in string you should specify word separators:

```
var words = hello.Split(new string[] {" ", ":"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); // you can pass other separators

var wordsCount = words.Length;
```

Comment: Basically showNumber is the length of the string array while hello.Length is the length of the string.

Comment: @SamMarion, yes, edited, thanks

Comment: Hello! Sorry, i should have been more precise with my problem here - i need to see how many words there are being used in the string. For example "Hello world!" should return "your string 'hello world' contains 2 words".

Comment: @RalfsR, see edited answer

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to split the string at all? `String` has a `Length` property so you can just use that:

```
 Console.WriteLine("the length of " + hello + " is " + hello.Length.ToString());
```

Your splitting only works if the string contains spaces, you are splitting on whitespace. That's for breaking a sentence into words, for example. You can use `"some string".ToCharArray()` if you want every character in a given string, and then count those.

Comment: Technically you don't have to call ToString to add ints to a string.